# Laravel 5.4 Eloquent SUM and ORDER BY pivot table column

Tags: php, mysql, laravel

I need an Eloquent query that retrieves the most purchased products in my database. The tables are `products`, `products_purchases`, `purchases`. Products and purchases both have a many-to-many relationship.

The pivot table `products_purchases` has a pivot field called `quantity`, which has the total quantity of a product bought on a purchase.

I tried to get the records like this:

```
$data['most_purchased'] = Products::whereHas('purchases', function($query){
        $query->selectRaw('SUM(products_purchases.quantity) AS qty')->orderBy('qty', 'desc')->groupBy('product_id');
})->get();
```

But it doesn't give accurate values, what is the right way to do this?

Comment: Is there a reason you using a raw SQL query to do this other than simply not knowing how to do it in Eloquent?

Comment: I used it because I needed an alias for that `SUM` to use in `ORDER BY`, I don't know if there is a way to give an alias when using an aggregate function such as `SUM`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This code works:

```
Products::join('products_purchases', 'product.id','=','products_purchases.product_id')
           ->selectRaw('product.*, SUM(products_purchases.quantity) AS qty')
           ->groupBy('product.id')
           ->orderBy('qty', 'desc')
           ->get();
```

But, is there another "cleaner" way to do this without using `join`?

Comment: You should edit your original question with this information rather than posting it as an answer. You can delete this answer if you choose to do so.

Comment: @PaydenK.Pringle Maybe, but it is a valid answer that people should be aware of, I don't select it as the accepted answer because it can be improved and it is not the best solution

Comment: What do you mean by cleaner? You are selecting data from two different tables - without multiple queries or denormalizing your schema, avoiding joins is not possible.

Comment: @Kaspars I didn’t say that joins should be avoided, I meant that maybe it could be done with the relation defined on the model using the “with” method.