# Laravel 5.8 How to order by sum of pivot table value in foreach?

Tags: laravel

I have the following tables:

parts:

```
id | name
1  | Lock
2  | Light
```

shelves:

```
id | name
1  | 1A
2  | 1B
```

part_shelf

```
id | part_id | shelf_id | stock
1  | 1       | 1        | 5
2  | 1       | 2        | 10
3  | 2       | 1        | 4
```

The relations:

In Part model:

```
public function shelves()
{
    return $this->belongsToMany( Shelf::class )->withPivot( 'stock' );
}
```

In shelf model:

```
public function parts()
{
    return $this->belongsToMany(Part::class)->withPivot('stock');
}
```

What I would like to do is order all the parts based on the total stock of the pivot table.

What I have tried is the following:

```
$parts = Part::all(); // This is inside controller

@foreach($parts->shelves()->orderBy('pivot_stock', 'desc') as $part)
@foreach($parts->shelves()->orderBy('part_shelf.stock', 'desc') as $part)
```

I do know that I can get the total stock for individual parts with:

```
$part->shelves()->sum('stock')
```

I just don't know how to approach it for all parts in the foreach-loop.

Also looked at other questions but that didn't really help:

- [How to order by pivot table data in Laravel's Eloquent ORM](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26551078/how-to-order-by-pivot-table-data-in-laravels-eloquent-orm)
- [Order by pivot table created_at in Laravel](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53222860/order-by-pivot-table-created-at-in-laravel)
- [Laravel 5.4 Eloquent SUM and ORDER BY pivot table column](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47296573/laravel-5-4-eloquent-sum-and-order-by-pivot-table-column) I think is the closest to what I'm looking for

Answer (score 0):

I had similar problem. I had three tables. Players (in my code "Igrac"), tournaments(in my code "Turnir_Piramida"), and players_tournaments pivot table(in my code "Nastup_piramida"). In pivot table was also column point for points for each player in each tournament. And i needed to summarize points from each player and then sort table by sum of points.

I manage to do that with third link you posted. You can see my solution on this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61396996/filter-data-with-pivot-table-laravel/61415119#61415119)