# Filter data with pivot table Laravel

Tags: laravel, many-to-many, pivot-table

I have three table:

- Igraci (as players in English)
- Turnir (as tournament in English)
- NastupTurnir (pivot table between this two)

I need to create table where will show all the players which will be the rows in the table, while columns will be tournaments. Value of this tournaments will be point which did player won on that tournament.

I manage to did this but whit one flaw. On my table it shows also players who doesn't have value for any of the tournaments.

How can I filter players to not show them in table?
[Problem](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WmtTV.jpg)

My codes:

**Controller.php**

```
<?php

  namespace App\Http\Controllers\Frontend;

  use App\Http\Controllers\Controller;
  use Illuminate\Http\Request;
  use App\Sezona;
  use App\Igrac;
  use App\TurnirPiramida;

  class RangListaPiramidaController extends Controller
  {
   public function index()
  {
    $sezone = Sezona::orderBy('godina', 'desc')->get();

    //$kola = TurnirPiramida::where('sezona_id', )

    //dd($igraci);
    return view("frontend.ranglista_piramida", compact('sezone'))->render();
}

public function show($id)
{
    $sezone = Sezona::orderBy('godina', 'desc')->get();

    $sezona = Sezona::findOrFail($id);

    $igraci = Igrac::get();

    $kola = TurnirPiramida::where('sezona_id', $id)->get();

    //$ups = Igrac::find(1);

    //dd($ups->igrac_piramida);

    return view("frontend.ranglista_piramida_kola", compact('sezone', 'sezona', 'igraci', 'kola'))->render();
}
}
```

**Blade file**

```
@extends('layouts.frontend')
@section('title', 'TK Pazin | Rang-liste Piramida')
@section('content')
<!-- Page Content -->
<div class="container">
<!-- Page Heading -->
<h1 class="my-4" style="text-align:center; color: #ba3631;">Rang-lista | Piramida {{ $sezona->godina }}</h1>
<nav aria-label="breadcrumb">
    <ol class="breadcrumb">
    @foreach($sezone as $sezona)
        <li class="breadcrumb-item"><a href="{{ route('ranglista.piramida.kola', $sezona->id) }}">{{ $sezona->godina }}</a></li>
    @endforeach
    </ol>
</nav>
<div>
    <div class="media mb-5">
        <div class="mr-3"><a href="../datoteke/Pravila-Pojedinačni-turniri.pdf" target="_blank"><i
            class="far fa-file-pdf fa-3x"></i></a></div>
        <div class="media-body mt-3">
            <a href="/datoteke/Pravila-Piramida.pdf" target="_blank">
            <h5 class="mt-0">Pravila
                natjecanja u piramidi
            </h5>
            </a>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>

<div class="table-responsive">
    <table class="table table-hover">
        <thead class="thead-dark">
            <tr>
            <th scope="col">#</th>
            <th scope="col">Ime i prezime</th>
            @foreach($kola as $kolo)
                <th scope="col">{{ $kolo->naziv }}</th>
            @endforeach
            <th scope="col">Ukupno</th>
            </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
            @foreach($igraci as $igrac)
            <tr>
                <th scope="row">1</th>
                <td>
                    <button type="button" class="btn btn-outline-primary" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#view_{{ $igrac->id }}">{{ $igrac->ime . " " . $igrac->prezime }}</button>
                    <!-- Modal -->
                    <div class="modal fade" id="view_{{ $igrac->id }}" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="exampleModalLabel" aria-hidden="true">
                        <div class="modal-dialog" role="document">
                            <div class="modal-content">
                                <div class="modal-header">
                                <h5 class="modal-title" id="exampleModalLabel">Natjecatelj: {{ $igrac->ime . " " . $igrac->prezime }}</h5>
                                <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close">
                                <span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span>
                                </button>
                                </div>
                                <div class="modal-body">
                                <div class="row">
                                    <div class="col-6">
                                        <img src="/img/avatar.png" alt="..." class="img-thumbnail">
                                    </div>
                                    <div class="col-6">
                                        <b>Prebivalište: </b>
                                        <p> {{ $igrac->prebivaliste }}</p>
                                        <b>Igra: </b>
                                        <p> {{ $igrac->igra }}</p>
                                        <b>Član kluba od:</b>
                                        <p> {{ $igrac->clanstvo }}. godine</p>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                                <hr>
                                <div class="row">
                                    <div class="col-12 col-md-5 card card-body m-2">
                                        <div class="row">
                                            <div class="col-8">
                                            <b>Najbolji ranking piramida: </b>
                                            </div>
                                            <div class="col-4">
                                            <span class="badge badge-success p-3">1.</span>
                                            </div>
                                        </div>
                                    </div>
                                    <div class="col-12 col-md-6 card card-body m-2">
                                        <div class="row">
                                            <div class="col-8">
                                            <b>Najbolji ranking pojedinačni turniri: </b>
                                            </div>
                                            <div class="col-4">
                                            <span class="badge badge-success p-3">5.</span>
                                            </div>
                                        </div>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                                </div>
                                <div class="modal-footer">
                                <button type="button" class="btn btn-secondary" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </td>
                    @foreach($kola as $kolo)
                        @foreach($igrac->igrac_piramida as $ip)
                            @if($ip->pivot->turnir_piramida_id == $kolo->id)
                                <td>{{ $ip->pivot->bodovi }}</td>
                            @endif
                        @endforeach
                    @endforeach

            </tr>
            @endforeach
        </tbody>
    </table>
</div>
</div>
<!-- /.container -->
@endsection
```

Answer (score 1):

If I understand properly, you want to fetch players that have been in a tournament.

You are currently fetching all player:

```php
$igraci = Igrac::get();
```

You should instead fetch only the players found in the tournament_player pivot table.

Get distinct player ids from the pivot table:

```php
$playerIds = DB::table('nastup_turnir')->groupBy('igrac_id')->pluck('igrac_id');
```

Fetch players from their ids:

```php
Igrac::whereIn('id', $playerIds)->get();
```

---

**Note:** Your pivot table doesn't follow Laravel naming convention. If you pivot table contains `igrac_id` and `turnir_id` columns, it should be named `igrac_turnir`.

Comment: You understand properly, but still I doesn't working.

Answer (score 0):

I manage to solve a problem.
Here is a code:

**Blade file**

```
@extends('layouts.frontend')
@section('title', 'TK Pazin | Rang-liste Piramida')
@section('content')
<!-- Page Content -->
<div class="container">
<!-- Page Heading -->
<h1 class="my-4" style="text-align:center; color: #ba3631;">Rang-lista | Piramida {{ $sezona->godina }}</h1>
<nav aria-label="breadcrumb">
    <ol class="breadcrumb">
    @foreach($sezone as $sezona)
        <li class="breadcrumb-item"><a href="{{ route('ranglista.piramida.kola', $sezona->id) }}">{{ $sezona->godina }}</a></li>
    @endforeach
    </ol>
</nav>
<div>
    <div class="media mb-5">
        <div class="mr-3"><a href="../datoteke/Pravila-Pojedinačni-turniri.pdf" target="_blank"><i
            class="far fa-file-pdf fa-3x"></i></a></div>
        <div class="media-body mt-3">
            <a href="/datoteke/Pravila-Piramida.pdf" target="_blank">
            <h5 class="mt-0">Pravila
                natjecanja u piramidi
            </h5>
            </a>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>

<div class="table-responsive">
    <table class="table table-hover">
        <thead class="thead-dark">
            <tr>
            <th scope="col">#</th>
            <th scope="col">Ime i prezime</th>
            @foreach($kola as $kolo)
                <th scope="col">{{ $kolo->naziv }}</th>
            @endforeach
            <th scope="col">Ukupno</th>
            </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
            @foreach($igraci as $igrac)
            <tr>
                <th scope="row">1</th>
                <td>
                    <button type="button" class="btn btn-outline-primary" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#view_{{ $igrac->id }}">{{ $igrac->ime . " " . $igrac->prezime }}</button>
                    <!-- Modal -->
                    <div class="modal fade" id="view_{{ $igrac->id }}" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="exampleModalLabel" aria-hidden="true">
                        <div class="modal-dialog" role="document">
                            <div class="modal-content">
                                <div class="modal-header">
                                <h5 class="modal-title" id="exampleModalLabel">Natjecatelj: {{ $igrac->ime . " " . $igrac->prezime }}</h5>
                                <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close">
                                <span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span>
                                </button>
                                </div>
                                <div class="modal-body">
                                <div class="row">
                                    <div class="col-6">
                                        <img src="/img/avatar.png" alt="..." class="img-thumbnail">
                                    </div>
                                    <div class="col-6">
                                        <b>Prebivalište: </b>
                                        <p> {{ $igrac->prebivaliste }}</p>
                                        <b>Igra: </b>
                                        <p> {{ $igrac->igra }}</p>
                                        <b>Član kluba od:</b>
                                        <p> {{ $igrac->clanstvo }}. godine</p>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                                <hr>
                                <div class="row">
                                    <div class="col-12 col-md-5 card card-body m-2">
                                        <div class="row">
                                            <div class="col-8">
                                            <b>Najbolji ranking piramida: </b>
                                            </div>
                                            <div class="col-4">
                                            <span class="badge badge-success p-3">1.</span>
                                            </div>
                                        </div>
                                    </div>
                                    <div class="col-12 col-md-6 card card-body m-2">
                                        <div class="row">
                                            <div class="col-8">
                                            <b>Najbolji ranking pojedinačni turniri: </b>
                                            </div>
                                            <div class="col-4">
                                            <span class="badge badge-success p-3">5.</span>
                                            </div>
                                        </div>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                                </div>
                                <div class="modal-footer">
                                <button type="button" class="btn btn-secondary" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </td>
                    @foreach($kola as $kolo)
                        @foreach($igrac->igrac_piramida as $ip)
                            @if($ip->pivot->turnir_piramida_id == $kolo->id)
                                <td>{{ $ip->pivot->bodovi }}</td>

                            @endif

                        @endforeach

                    @endforeach
                    <td>{{ $igrac->igrac_piramida()->whereIn('turnir_piramida_id', $kola_id)->sum('bodovi') }}</td>
            </tr>
            @endforeach
        </tbody>
    </table>
</div>
</div>
<!-- /.container -->
@endsection
```

**Controller file**

```
<?php

  namespace App\Http\Controllers\Frontend;

  use App\Http\Controllers\Controller;
  use Illuminate\Http\Request;
  use App\Sezona;
  use App\Igrac;
  use App\TurnirPiramida;
  use DB;
  use App\NastupPiramida;

  class RangListaPiramidaController extends Controller
  {
   public function show($id)
   {
    $sezone = Sezona::orderBy('godina', 'desc')->get();

    $sezona = Sezona::findOrFail($id);

    //Sva kola koja su u toj sezoni, u array spremi id od tih kola
    $kola_id = TurnirPiramida::where('sezona_id', $id)->pluck('id');

    //Svi id-evi igraca koji su u tom kolu spremi u array
    $odabrani = NastupPiramida::where('turnir_piramida_id', $kola_id)->pluck('igrac_id');

    $igraci = Igrac::whereIn('id', $odabrani)
    ->leftjoin('nastup_piramidas', 'igracs.id','=','nastup_piramidas.igrac_id')
    ->whereIn('nastup_piramidas.turnir_piramida_id', $kola_id)
    ->selectRaw('igracs.*, SUM(nastup_piramidas.bodovi) AS ukupno')
    ->groupBy('igracs.id')
    ->orderBy('ukupno', 'desc')
    ->get();

    $kola = TurnirPiramida::where('sezona_id', $id)->get();

    return view("frontend.ranglista_piramida_kola", compact('sezone', 'sezona', 'igraci', 'kola', 'kola_id'))->render();
}
}
```